# Overlaying rasters with different dimensions

Tags: qgis, raster, zonal-statistics, overlay

I am new in QGIS. I have [several (108) rasters](https://zenodo.org/record/5090419#.YzL4j-zMI1J) (each one representing the global distribution of a specific species), I want to combine with a vector file representing different regions of the world, to know what are the different species we can find in each region of the vector.

My plan to do that is to overlay the different rasters in one "compiled" dataset, and then to apply the Zonal Statistics Tool on this compiled dataset and on my vector file (representing regions). Maybe there is a more effective way to do so.

I am self-learning QGIS and I think I read that it is not possible to overlay different rasters together if they do not have the same dimensions or orientation. Nonetheless, in the rasters description, the authors mention that " The spatial grain of map rasters varies from 10 minutes to 1 degree of latitude and longitude".
How could I proceed in order to overlay all my rasters? Or would you see a better method to get the final information I need (distribution of all species per region)

Comment: As long as the raster are georeferenced (with known extent, SRID) you will be on the safe side and there shouldnt be an issue with overlaying them.

Comment: (I have not tried it with differenct crs) I would try [Build Virtual Raster](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_miscellaneous/buildvirtualraster.html)